# Does this search function look any good?

Tags: c, string, search

I'm new to C so I've been playing around with it for a bit and came up with this search function which I plan to move into a search and replace function. I'm sure it works since I've been testing it with a bunch of inputs and always getting the corresponding amount of "Word found!" prints.

```
void searchString() {
    char message[] = "This is a test message test test";
    char wordToFind[] = "message";

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(message) - 1; i++) {
        if (message[i] == wordToFind[0]) {
            int i2 = 0;
            for (i2 = 1; i2 < sizeof(wordToFind) - 1; i2++) {
                if (message[i + i2] != wordToFind[i2]) {
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
                if (i2 == sizeof(wordToFind) - 2) {
                    printf("Word found!\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, is this efficient or is there a much better way to do this in C?

Comment: First impression is that there are *way* too many levels of indentation. As a rule of thumb, if you have more than three, rewrite the code. Also note that `sizeof` will give surprising results if, say, passed a pointer. I think you mean `strlen`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at it and thinking the same thing. I feel that I could find a way to do away with the second for loop all together.

Comment: Ah, just read up on strlen() and that looks much more like what I meant to use

Comment: this is not gonna work , because you are incrementing the value of `i` twice , assume that the value of `message` equal to `"mmessage"` and `wordToFind` equal to `"message"` , then this code outputs the wrong answer

Comment: If you want a better way to search for a substring, then consider an entirely different algorithm like [Boyer Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your function:

- When you detect a mismatch, you increment `i` twice, hence you would not find `message` in `This is a test mmessage test test`.
- You hard code the string lengths. Using `sizeof()` is only possible for strings known at compile time so your function is not generic at all. You should instead write a function that takes 2 pointers to C strings and use `strlen()` sparingly or check for the null terminators in the loops.

Here is a modified version that is more generic:

```
void searchString(const char *message, const char *wordToFind) {

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (message[i] == wordToFind[0]) {
            int i2 = 0;
            for (i2 = 1; wordToFind[i2] != '\0'; i2++) {
                if (message[i + i2] != wordToFind[i2]) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (wordToFind[i2] == '\0') {
                printf("Word found at offset %d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- your function does not handle the special case of an empty `wordToFind[]`.
- In terms of efficiency, it would probably be more efficient to use the standard library function `strstr()` as it might be implemented in a very efficient way.

Here is an alternative with `strstr()`:

```
void searchString(const char *message, const char *wordToFind) {
    for (const char *p = message; (p = strstr(p, wordToFind)) != NULL; p++) {
        printf("Word found at offset %d\n", (int)(p - message));
        if (*p == '\0') { /* handle special case of empty wordToFind */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `strlen` does not find the length by magic.  It must scan each and every character to find the trailing null.  Which is an O(n) algorithm.  If you iterate through every character and call `strlen()` each iteration, then you've got an O(n^2) algorithm.  What chqrlie has done by checking for the trailing null is much better.  If n and m are the lengths of message and wordToFind, his code is O(nm) while using strlen() each iteration would be O(n^2 m^2).  (unless the compiler is smart enough to optimize the strlen() as a loop invariant for you).

Comment: @TrentP: I amended the answer regarding the use of `strlen()`.  Note that the complexity has a worst case of **O(n.m)** if the `wordToFind` has a long prefix that matches a significant portion of `message`, but an average case of just slightly more than **O(n)**.